# Multi-Language Websites

Tags: language-translation

Can anyone recommend a good option to translate websites into Spanish? We tried using the Google translate plugin but the translation was so rough (very inaccurate, bordering on embarrassing the company) we had to hire a company to refine the translation so that it was much more accurate which makes for an extremely inefficient process for updating the site moving forward.

We're in health insurance, so the language we're translating is very specialized in nature and needs to be accurate for our members. To make it even more complicated, the Google Translate plugin happens instantly, so the translation is live before we have a chance to refine it before users can see it. In other words, there's no way to refine the translation before you make the content visible to users in the production environment. This is a legal regulatory requirement for Covered California and the Affordable Care Act, so it has to be a top notch implementation.

Short of a proxy solution that intercepts the content before it hits the production site or a separate site coded in Spanish, I'm not sure what other solutions exist if any. Ideas?  The separate site solution is also problematic because it requires a bilingual staff and it doubles the work because both environments have to mirror each other exactly at all times.

Recommendations? Ideas? Any suggestions based on experience are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hire developer - he will describe all you need. You will never do it by your own. If you already have - hire new one, he will know how to do it. Question is very spiciefied but any (let's take for example php) php-engine (framework) or even custom php-engine can be updated the way you want.

Preview before upload to public? Easy! Change by moderator|admin values of translations? Easy! Main thing that each sentence (or even paragraph) you will describe by your own... I don't want describe all mechanism of it - hire developer and he will do all you need. $)

Comment: Hmm this is the solution recommended by our development team. It's not that easy when they are your Agency of Record (AOR) Hiring a new agency requires discovery, time, and a new contract. Not to mention all of the political ramifications. The corporate landscape can be pretty difficult to navigate. Thanks for the suggestions but there's not much meat on the bone to work with here.

Comment: Do you understand that now we are talking about 'abstract' items? Show you have - maybe some one will suggest solutions. All others solutions 'your dev-team' know. Question is failed on start. $)